# Parse json to custom format

Tags: json, ansible, format

I have a file with json format like this

```json
[
  {
    "name": "enable_replica",
    "value": "on"
  },
  {
    "name": "enable_production",
    "value": "on"
  },
  {
    "name": "max_replica",
    "value": "10"
  },
  {
    "name": "min_replica",
    "value": "5"
  }
]
```

I need to format it to string so it will look like this

```
enable_replica=on,enable_production=on,max_replica=10,min_replica=5
```

I tried using json_query but it still does not work

```yaml
- command: "cat ~/config.json"
  register: config

- set_fact:
    database_flags: "{{ config.stdout | from_json | json_query('[*]') | join(',') }}"
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and define ["does not work"](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the reformatting solely with JMESPath.
You would just have to leverage the possibilities of the [`join` function](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#join).

So, given the fact:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    database_flags: "{{
        config.stdout
        | from_json
        | json_query('[].join(`=`, [name, value]) | join(`,`, @)')
      }}"
```

A `debug` on `database_flags` would yield you:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  database_flags: enable_replica=on,enable_production=on,max_replica=10,min_replica=5
```